# Find sum of hours for each date worked

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

I have a table of timesheet entries set up like this:

| id | job_id | employee_id | hours_worked | date_worked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 111 | 8 | 2022-10-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 222 | 8 | 2022-10-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 222 | 8 | 2022-10-02 |
| 4 | 2 | 222 | 8 | 2022-10-03 |
| 5 | 2 | 111 | 8 | 2022-10-04 |
| 6 | 2 | 222 | 5 | 2022-10-05 |
| 7 | 3 | 111 | 8 | 2022-10-04 |
| 8 | 4 | 333 | 8 | 2022-10-07 |
| 9 | 4 | 111 | 3 | 2022-10-09 |

I'm trying to find the sum of hours for the first, second, third etc dates that work was done on each job

Ideally I'd like something like this:

| job_id | Day1_hours | Day2_hours | Day3_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 8 | 0 |
| 2 | 8 | 8 | 5 |
| 3 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 8 | 3 | 0 |

The trouble I'm running into is that there can be multiple employees working on each day of the job, so using a query to select the min(date_worked) greater than a subquery for min(date_worked) is sometimes giving me the same dates. There are sometimes days in between work done on a job, so I can't just add a day to the minimum value and check hours for that date.

How can I find the sum of hours_worked for the first date_worked, then the second, third etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIVOT's are great but conditional aggregations offer a bit more flexibility

**Example**

```
Select job_id
      ,[Day1_Hours] = sum( case when DN=1 then hours_worked else 0 end)
      ,[Day2_Hours] = sum( case when DN=2 then hours_worked else 0 end)
      ,[Day3_Hours] = sum( case when DN=3 then hours_worked else 0 end)
 From ( Select *
              ,DN = dense_rank() over (partition by job_id order by date_worked)
         From  YourTable
      ) A
 Group By Job_ID
```

Comment: you have a typo on day3_hours

Comment: also, isn't this just another way to pivot? what's the reason to go this route? I don't have a lot of experience so just wondering.

Comment: @DannySlor it is another way to pivot, for a small number of columns its simpler and often performs better.

Comment: @DannySlor As I mentioned conditional aggregation offers a bit more flexibility.    For example, It would be a small matter to add a TOTAL or AVERAGE or even additional attributes

Comment: @DannySlor Good catch on the typo.   Bad copy/paste

Comment: @DannySlor You may also notice with the ELSE 0   there are no NULL values.   Removing NULLS in a PIVOT would require a ISNULL([1],0) or coalesce([1],0) or case ...

Comment: I did notice the null thing, but  it makes more sense to me for it to be null than zero.

Comment: @DannySlor Not going to disagree with you,  NULLs say more than zero, but OP's desired results shows zero.  That said, it NULLs are required, just remove the ELSE 0

Answer (score 1):

```
select job_id
      ,[1] as day1_hours
      ,[2] as day2_hours
      ,[3] as day3_hours
from   (
       select  job_id 
              ,hours_worked
              ,dense_rank() over(partition by job_id order by date_worked) as days
       from   t
       ) t
pivot  (sum(hours_worked) for days in([1],[2],[3])) p
```

| job_id | day1_hours | day2_hours | day3_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 8 | null |
| 2 | 8 | 8 | 5 |
| 3 | 8 | null | null |
| 4 | 8 | 3 | null |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8rhTRcYd)